# escaping data passed by python to Javascript (JSON)

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have some data that I need to pass to JavaScript on a page. I'm using jinja2 to generate my page and here's how this is going:

In python:

```
some_json_data = json.dumps(some_data)
```

In jinja2:

```
JSON.parse('{% autoescape off %}{{ some_json_data }}{% endautoescape %}')
```

However, sometimes, `some_json_data` could contain strings with `\n` as well as `'`. Is there a library/some known function that I could use to escape these?

I know I could write this function with no problem, but I was wondering if there's already a library or something that does this. I've been looking around and haven't found anything.

Side note: My application is built on using Flask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `JSON.parse`; the output is already valid JavaScript. You then don't need to put quotes around the JSON value either.

Generally, my JavaScript looks like:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var serverJSValue = {% autoescape off %}{{ some_json_data }}{% endautoescape %};
</script>
```

Comment: ... I cannot believe I overlooked something so simple. Thanks. Will accept once allowed.